# Proving sum of complex roots is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, geometric-progressions

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the complex roots of $z^3 =1$. Show that the sum of the first $n$ terms in the series $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 +...$ is either $0, 1$ or $-\alpha^2$ depending on the remainder when $n$ is divided by $3$

For each case I have considered a GP sum:

$\text{If }n\equiv 0\:\left(\text{mod 3}\right)$, then $S_n=\frac{1-\alpha ^{3n}}{1-\alpha }$

$\text{If }n\equiv 1\:\left(\text{mod 3}\right)$, then $S_n=\frac{1-\alpha ^{3n+1}}{1-\alpha }$

$\text{If }n\equiv 2\:\left(\text{mod 3}\right)$, then $S_n=\frac{1-\alpha ^{3n+2}}{1-\alpha }$

I have tried algebraic manipulation but I can seem to show that they are equal to $0, 1 $ or $-\alpha^2$. I'm sure I would be able to algebraically manipulate the sums to a final term but I can't so I am thinking instead - are my GP sums correct?

Comment: Surely $S_n = { 1- \alpha^{n+1} \over 1- \alpha}$ for al $n$? The term $1- \alpha^{n+1}$ can only have 3 possible values.

Comment: In your attempt, you have already found the answer. If $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then $\alpha^{3k} = 1$ so that $S_n = 0$. If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then $\alpha^{3k + 1} = \alpha$ so that $S_n = 1$. And in the last one, you would get $S_n = \dfrac{1 - \alpha^2}{1 - \alpha} = 1 + \alpha = - \alpha^2$ since $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 = 0$.

Comment: I see. So my approach was correct, I was just not thinking properly. @Arthur I'm not very geometrically-inclined but it seems like an interesting alternate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the first $n$ terms, in any case, is given by $S_n=\frac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}$.
Now we can evaluate $S_n$ in each of the three cases:

(a) If $n\equiv 0\, (\mathrm{mod}\, 3)$, then $n=3k$ for some integer $k$, hence $\alpha^n=\alpha^{3k}=(\alpha^3)^k=1^k=1$, so $S_n=0$;

(b) If $n\equiv 1\, (\mathrm{mod}\, 3)$, then $n=3k+1$ for some integer $k$, hence $\alpha^n=\alpha^{3k+1}=\alpha(\alpha^3)^k=\alpha$, so $S_n=1$;

(c) If $n\equiv 2\, (\mathrm{mod}\, 3)$, then $n=3k+2$ for some integer $k$, hence $\alpha^n=\alpha^{3k+2}=\alpha^2(\alpha^3)^k=\alpha^2$, so $S_n=\frac{1-\alpha^2}{1-\alpha}=1+\alpha=-\alpha^2$.

Comment: So what I was missing was the fact that $\alpha^3 = 1$. Whoops.

Comment: My apologies. I cannot count./

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ is a root of $$0=z^3-1=(z-1)(z^2+z+1)$$ Since $\alpha\neq1$, we get that $\alpha$ is a root of $z^2+z+1=0$. Said differently, we have
$$
\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0
$$
This immediately implies for any $n\geq0$ that
$$
S_{n+3}=\alpha^{n}(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)+S_n=S_n
$$
From here, it's not difficult to see that $S_0=0$, $S_1=1$ and $S_2=1+\alpha=-\alpha^2$ are the only three values that appear, in order, repeating indefinitely. An induction proof formalizes this neatly.

---

Geometrically, we have this picture (remember that $\beta = \alpha^2$ and $1 = \alpha^3$, click for larger version):

[image]

Here you see $\alpha, \beta$ and the first four partial sums $S_0, S_1, S_2, S_3$ marked as points in the complex plane. The line from $S_1$ to $S_2$ is blue like the line from the origin to $\alpha$ to illustrate $S_1+\alpha = S_2$. And correspondingly for the two red lines with $\beta = \alpha^2$.

Comment: $S_{n+3}=\alpha^{n}(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)+S_n=S_n$ this is especially nice. I will keep this in mind for future

Comment: I dont 100% understand your argand diagram though. What is the significance of the blue and red lines? I think S0, S1, S2 and S3 are showing the values (repeating)

Comment: @user71207 The red lines are vectors corresponding to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively. Once each centered at the origin, and once each centered at the relevant $S_n$ that they are added to. I maybe should've actually added an explanation there.

Comment: But $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugates so why is the red line straight? Shouldn't it be a reflection over the real axis, making a V-shape?

Comment: @user71207 Those are two separate red lines. One from $0$ to $\beta$, one from $S_2$ to $S_3$. They both correspond to the action of "adding $\beta$", to $0$ and to $S_2$ respectively.